# Skype shows online status even when I changed password and loged out

Tags: login, skype, logout

I suspected my account may have been signed in elsewhere, so I changed my password to force sign out, but nothing improved; my status still appears online to my contacts.

Comment: which version of skype do you use?

Comment: @TheJoker : Thanks for Reply , I used version 6.11.0.102

Comment: May be it has got something to do with the version. I'm using Skype version 6.16.0.105 & I don't face any problems.

Comment: Okey, I was asking update, but I ignored. So, I will try to update and let you know.

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try the "/remotelogout" chat command.

http://community.skype.com/t5/Windows-archive/Always-logged-in/m-p/2986124#M241342

Comment: Thanks, I will try it and update you  when I get time :-)